# Search table view using multiple filters

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to ask how can I search with multiple filters in searchDisplayController

here is my method:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    self.filteredCandies = self.person.filter({( candy: Candy) -> Bool in

        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)

        let stringMatch = candy.name.rangeOfString(searchText)

        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
```

Comment: What delimiter for search terms are you going to be using in your search bar? Commas, spaces, '|' etc...

Comment: Only spces and I want my content to be displayed wheter i start searching with upper or lowercase letter. Ex: When I search iPhone or Iphone the table view should display the iPhone cell. Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is split out the search text on your delimiter (spaces) and filter the results based on the different searches you could be doing.

Here is a quick example that I came up with in a playground.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var searchText = "i F"
var arrayOfThingsIWantToSearch: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]
var searchTerms: [String] = split(searchText) {$0 == " "} //split out our search text on spaces to get multiple search terms

var filtered: [String] = []

for item in arrayOfThingsIWantToSearch {
    for searchTerm in searchTerms {
        if (item as NSString).containsString(searchTerm) {
            filtered.append(item)
            break
        }
    }
}

print(filtered) //prints "[Four, Five, Six, Eight, Nine]"
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I still can't understand how to implement this in my project.